# Plot many functions from Table with separate graph

Tags: plotting, functions, list-manipulation, legending

Does anyone how can I plot this?
I got many errors saying Infinite expression 1/0.
I want to plot each one on a separate graph from top to bottom with legend about the values of a, b, c, m, n, p.

```
f1[a_, b_, c_, d_, m_, n_, p_] := -((m + d (a + b - m - n) + n) /(
c d + p - d p));

Block[{t =
Table[f1[a, b, c, d, m, n,
p], {a, {-1, 0, 1}}, {b, {-1, 0, 1}}, {c, {-1, 0, 1}}, {m, {-1,
0, 1}}, {n, {-1, 0, 1}}, {p, {-1, 0, 1}}]}, Plot[t, {d, 0, 1},PlotLegends ->{"a" = a, "b" = b, "c"=c, "d"=d, "m" = m, "n" =n, "p" = p]]
```

Comment: Try `f1[a_,b_,c_,d_,m_,n_,p_]:=If[(c*d+p-d*p)==0,0,-((m+d(a+b-m-n)+n)/(c*d+p-d*p))];
Table[Print[Plot[f1[a,b,c,d,m,n,p],{d,0,1},PlotLegends->"{a,b,c,m,n,p}="<>ToString[{a,b,c,m,n,p}]]],{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1},{c,-1,1},{m,-1,1},{n,-1,1},{p,-1,1}];`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to look at the various plots.

```
f1[a_, b_, c_, d_, m_, n_, p_] := 
  ConditionalExpression[-((m + d (a + b - m - n) + n)/(c*d + p - d*p)), 
    (c*d + p - d*p) != 0];

Manipulate[
 Plot[f1[a, b, c, d, m, n, p], {d, 0, 1},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (
    Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"d", "f1(d)"}),
  PlotLabel -> "{a,b,c,m,n,p} = " <>
    ToString[{a, b, c, m, n, p}]],
 {{step, 1}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 1}},
 Delimiter,
 {{a, -1}, -1, 1, step, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0}, -1, 1, step, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, -1}, -1, 1, step, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 0}, -1, 1, step, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{n, 0}, -1, 1, step, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{p, 1}, -1, 1, step, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]